# Referencing a model in Angular with `(ngModelChange)`?

Tags: javascript, angular

Simplification : I have a calculator which won't allow "7" to be the result ( `valid` will be `false`).

[image]

The calculator itself is component which implements `ControlValueAccessor`.

The model is

```
interface IModel {
  a, b, c: number | null; 
}
```

*(`a` is the left digit , `b` is the middle one , and `c` is the result)*

This is how I wrote the template :

```
 <input type='text' [ngModel]='myModel.a'   (ngModelChange)='calc("a",$event)'/> + 
 <input type='text' [ngModel]='myModel.b'   (ngModelChange)='calc("b",$event)'/> = 
 <input type='text' readonly [ngModel]='myModel.c'   />
```

I didn't use banana in a box becuase I had to do a logic on each modification of the inputs.
I didn't use getter/setter either becuase otherwise- in the setter - I'd would have problem with controlling updates.

So that's why I use `(ngModelChange)` . Where on each change I call the `calc` function :

```
 calc(propName,e) {
    this.myModel[propName] = e;
    this.myModel.c = +this.myModel.a + +this.myModel.b;
    this.onChangeCallback(this.myModel);
  }
```

But now things get complicated.

When changing the first input , I must tell the `calc` function  :

- To update the model  for the control who activated the change - that's why I send  "a" in  `calc("a",$event)` and "b" in `calc("b",$event)`.
- Run calculation against the updated model.

But this correlation seems WRONG to me :

[image]

Sure - I could add template variable to each and send that variable and to read `.value` in the calc function.

But I think I'm going into the non-angular way

**Question**

How can I reference the  model of the control  when updating the input? ( Along with doing  custom logic when set)

[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-controlvalueeaccessor-with-validator-npt-allowed-xqzfzr?file=app/hello.component.ts)

*PS - I don't have  the `(input)` event since i'm using  Angular in Nativescript.*

Comment: you can use reactive from approch much clearner way , I can provide answer if you want

Comment: @PranayRana Sure why not ? it will help the community  !

Comment: Check my answer might find helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `banana in a box` and your custom logic together.

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gactgp?file=app/app.component.ts)

You can use `[(ngModel)]` and `(ngModelChange)="calc($event)"` together. What this will do is to update your model first and then call your custom function.

So, change your markup as follows

```html
<input type='text' [(ngModel)]='myModel.a'   (ngModelChange)='calc()'/> + 
<input type='text' [(ngModel)]='myModel.b'   (ngModelChange)='calc()'/> = 
<input type='text' readonly [ngModel]='myModel.c'/>
```

`calc` method:

```
calc() {
   this.myModel.c = this.myModel.a * 1 + this.myModel.b * 1
}
```

Note: `* 1` is for parsing string to number. It's a hack I'd like to use.

Comment: ^ This is what I was hoping  hoped  to find ! much simpler.  Thanks. BTW I use `+X` instead of `*1`. You can see it in the `+`'s   here : `this.myModel.c = +this.myModel.a + +this.myModel.b;`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I thought those were just typos. Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, actually it is not necessary, since you are the one updating the value, not the input itself. I'll change it to the way it was.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reactive from like this , Not much in template file i.e. html , all dirty stuff handle by Typescript

```
<form class="form-horizontal"  [formGroup]="calculationForm" novalidate >
     <input type='text' "formControlName"='a'  /> + 
     <input type='text' "formControlName"='b'/> = 
     <input type='text' "formControlName"='c'   />
</form>
```

Ts file would be

```
      createForm() {
        this.calculationForm= this.fb.group({
          a: '',
          b: '',
          c: ''
        });
      }

  get a() {
    return this.calculationForm.get('a');
  }

  get b() {
    return this.calculationForm.get('b');
  }

  get c() {
    return this.calculationForm.get('c');
  }

    private onChanges(): void {
        this.a.valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.calculate());
        this.b.valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.calculate());
    }

  private calculate() {
        if (this.a.value && this.b.value) {
         this.c.setValue(this.a.value + this.b.value , {emitEvent: false});
        }
    }
```